# Generate the password hash using php

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, sha1, silverstripe

i have a DB of users and their password in encrypted form. I want to let the users log in to the site using the username and password. For authentication i need to know what type of encryption is their so that i can match the entered password with the stored password. I have tried many algorithm but i am not able to workout the encryption mechanism. here is a test case

**original password**: alvin

**Password in DB** :f9b0213127225c1c74d6662dee8acca297eff9e0

**Password Encryption** : sha1_v2.4.

**salt**: 9j1jyse241v7cw0s8okkssgg448wgcogsggoww0

What i want to do is to create the password in DB from original password.

Any hints on how to convert the original password to the password in DB

P.S the table was created by silverstripe CMS

**EDIT**:

We are no longer using the silverstripe CMS and are converting our website to a Mobile App. So using silverstripe or its function is not an option. However we are using the member table with all the member's data in it including authentication information.

Comment: If the passwords in the database are hashed, then forget trying to decode them; and there is ___never___ any need to know what the value of a user's password is

Comment: Its going to be more or less impossible to figure this out. Just add a flag to the table to determine if the user has been upgraded to your new algorithm (e.g. password_hash) or not, and if not, force them to change their password on next login.

Comment: SilverStripe handles this out of the box with the [Member](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-Member.html) class. The SilverStripe log in form will take care of all of this for you. There is no need to reinvent this functionality.

Comment: @MarkBaker We do not need to know the user password. We need to be able to convert a password from the login form, encrypt it and copmpare it with the stored encrypted password to authenticate a user. Unfortunately  we are not able to figure out the exact encryption

Comment: @3dgoo We are moving away from silverstripe but keeping the user DB so using silverstripe functions or classes is not possible

Comment: @developerwjk Issue is we are not able to authenticate a user. To authenticate a user we need to be able to take the password from the login form, encrypt it and then compare it to the one in the DB. We are not able to encrypt a password because we have no information about the encryption technique used to encrypt the password that are already in the DB

Comment: Well the original silverstripe code must have the code to handle authentication, so while you aren't still using it, you should still be able to read the code and see the method/hashing that it uses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of hate in the OP's comments. But it's misdirected - OP is **not trying to *decode*** anything (and has explained it better on the forum: http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/migrating-a-site-to-silverstripe/show/101337)

In short, is trying to ***authenticate* a user from an *external* source**, using SilverStripe's database (so using the Member class directly isn't a thing).

#### To provide an actual answer:

The encryption method is stored on the Member table, which by default is 'blowfish', and can change per user.
You need three fields of data:

- Member.PasswordEncryption
- Member.Salt
- Member.Password

The first defines how to use the second, which then allows the third to be calculated (and thus checked against).

Reasonably standard stuff. See the classes defined here for more detailed/specific info (cf. "Direct known subclasses"):
http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PasswordEncryptor.html

Comment: Thanks @agal. I looked into the password encryptor yesterday. Did not find the answer. However, your answer made me look deeper and i think i have got the solution. It is simple concatenation of password and salt to generate the encrypted password Thanks mate